# R: knitrBootstrap in RStudio using YAML front matter

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am attempting to compile a `knitr` MWE using the `knitrBootstrap` package. I am using the `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`K` shortcut key in RStudio, which essentially calls the `knit` function from `knitr`.

Here is the MWE I am trying to compile, which is basically the MWE given on Jim Hester's `knitrBootstrap` page [here](https://github.com/jimhester/knitrBootstrap#yaml-front-matter):

````
---
author: "FG"
date: "Tuesday, April 29, 2014"
output:
  knitrBootstrap::bootstrap_document:
    title: "Test LaTeX"
    theme: journal
    highlight: visual studio
    theme.chooser: TRUE
    highlight.chooser: TRUE
---

```{r}
x = a + b
```

$$ 
\begin{align}
x^2 + \mathbf{y}^2
\end{align}
$$
````

However, this gives me the

> Error: 'bootstrap_document' is not an exported object from
>   'namespace:knitrBootstrap' Execution halted

That `bootstrap_document` is not a function exported from the namespace of `knitrBootstrap` is easy to verify. Has something changed since the page on Jim Hester's blog was written?

Comment: bootstrap_document *is* a function exported by the knitrBootstrap package (line 4 of the NAMESPACE file). So you've broken something...

Comment: @Spacedman Nope. Here's a better deduction -- most people get packages from [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitrBootstrap/index.html) (if available). Anyway, thanks for that, getting the package from github works.

Comment: That's not what the instructions on that page say. Looks like you need version from github.

Comment: Yes as you have discovered you need the version from github in order to use the knitrBootstrap package with rmarkdown.  I can't put the latest version on CRAN until the rmarkdown package is also released on CRAN, sorry!

Comment: @Jim Thanks much. `knitrBootstrap` looks like a great package -- look forward to using it.

Comment: @Jim Quick followup question. Can I include the `fragment_only` option of `markdownToHTML` as YAML front matter? I tried and the `render` function complained. I am basically trying to produce output that I can plug into my blog.

Comment: `markdownToHTML` and the `fragment_only` option are in the `markdown` package, not the `rmarkdown` package that knitrBootstrap uses now.  There is probably a way to do what you are attempting, but the explanation is not going to fit in a comment, make a new question (with a reproducible example) and I will try to answer it.

Comment: @Jim I was going to do just that. Will leave a note here for you when I do.